# Is $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}}$ equivalent to its category of endofunctors?

Tags: category-theory, functors

This is a particular case of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/334266/461).

For any categories $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$, write $\mathcal D^{\mathcal C}$ for the category of functors from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal D$.

Set $\mathcal C:=\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}}$.

> Is $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ equivalent to $\mathcal C$?

Note that $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}}$ is **not** equivalent to $\mathsf{Set}$. Indeed, for any category $\mathcal A$ with terminal object $1$ and coproduct $2:=1\sqcup1$, and any object $A$ of $\mathcal A$, write $P(A)$ for the statement "there are exactly two morphisms from $A$ to $2$ in $\mathcal A$". In $\mathsf{Set}$ the condition $P(X)$ implies $X\simeq1$, whereas in $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}}$ any representable functor $F$ satisfies $P(F)$ by the Yoneda Lemma. This is easily seen to imply $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}}\not\sim\mathsf{Set}$.

Comment: What is your question? It looks like you already answered it. If you want to characterize which categories $C^C$ is equivalent to $C$, you should think of the cartesian closed structure of the (meta)category of categories. You should be able to prove the terminal category $1$ is the only one which works.

Comment: @Rachmaninoff - What I know is that $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}}$ is not equivalent to $\mathsf{Set}$. The question is: Is $(\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}})^{(\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}})}$ equivalent to $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}}$?

Comment: Is $C$ even locally small? Does $C^C$ even exist as a functor category?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - Yes, there are various ways of interpreting the question. My own way would be to consider only categories whose collections of objects and morphisms are *sets*, and admit the axiom of universes (in which case the answer depends *a priori* on the chosen universe), but I thought it was better to let the readers choose their own interpretation.