# Possible similarities between a category and its category of endofunctors

Tags: category-theory, functors

The poset variant of this question is posted separately [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3302516/660).

For any category $\mathcal C$ write $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ for its category of endofunctors.

Consider the following properties a category $\mathcal C$ may or may not have:

(P1) $\mathcal C$ is equivalent to a category with exactly one object and one morphism,

(P2) $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ is equivalent to $\mathcal C$,

(P3) there is a fully faithful functor $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}\to\mathcal C$,

(P4) there is an essentially surjective functor $\mathcal C\to\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$.

Clearly (P1) implies (P2), and (P2) implies (P3) and (P4):
$$
\begin{matrix}
&&1\\ 
&&\downarrow\\ 
&&2\\ 
&\swarrow&&\searrow\\ 
3&&&&4.
\end{matrix}
$$
Denote by (Qij) the question "Does (Pi) imply (Pj)?".

Question (Q21) was asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/334266/461). Let us ask also:

> **Question (Q31)** Does (P3) imply (P1)?
>
> **Question (Q41)** Does (P4) imply (P1)?
>
> **Question (Q32)** Does (P3) imply (P2)?
>
> **Question (Q42)** Does (P4) imply (P2)?
>
> **Question (Q34)** Does (P3) imply (P4)?
>
> **Question (Q43)** Does (P4) imply (P3)?

There are very natural categories for which I don't know which of the properties (P2), (P3) or (P4) hold. Let (Qi,$\mathcal C$) be the question "Does the category $\mathcal C$ have Property (Pi)?". In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3295737/660), Question (Q2,$\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}}$) was asked and Question (Q2,$\mathsf{Set}$) was answered negatively.

> (Q3,$\mathsf{Set}$) Does $\mathsf{Set}$ have Property (P3)?
>
> (Q4,$\mathsf{Set}$) Does $\mathsf{Set}$ have Property (P4)?
>
> (Q3,$\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}}$) Does $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}}$ have Property (P3)?
>
> (Q4,$\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}}$) Does $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{Set}}$ have Property (P4)?

Comment: Related question posted on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/337347/461